# Dynamic routing depending on servers response in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to configure my application in a way that lets it route dynamically depending on the servers response. My code is as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CategoriesController" class="column">
    <div  layout-align="center center" ng-repeat="category in categories" >

        <div class="category-button-text-english">{{category}}</div>
        <md-button ng-click="submit()" class="category-button"  aria-label="{{category}}">
            <img ng-src="assets/images/categories/{{category}}.png"
                 alt="{{category}}">
        </md-button>
        <div class="category-button-text-translation">
            {{category|uppercase| translate}}
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.submit=function(){
     subCategoryService.getsubCategories().then(function (response) 
        {
            console.log(response)
          $rootScope.subcategories=response.data.data.subcategories;
          $scope.category=response.data.data.category_name;          
                                       })
          $location.path('/subcategory');    

}
```

**Service**

```
 .factory('subCategoryService', ['$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', '$cookies','$rootScope', function ($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike, $cookies,$rootScope,category){
          var url2 = 'localhost:5000/api/subcategories/';
        return {getsubCategories: function () {
                return $http.get(url2);

            }}}])
```

Another controller that gives the category names from server's response before the application comes on category page.

```
controller("userTypeController", function ($rootScope,$scope, $location, CategoryService) {
$scope.getCat=function(){
    CategoryService.getCategories() .then(function (response) 
        {
          $rootScope.categories=response.data.data.categories;

                                       });
    $location.path('/category');
};
```

So what I want is that after getting the category names from the server, it calls the right route depending on what button is clicked on the category page. For example depending on what button is clicked, the call should go like 
`localhost:5000/api/subcategories/CATEGORY_NAME`. I get an array of categories when I go through the user type service and I want to use one of those category names to be passed in the subcategory service just as I wrote earlier. The flow of the application is like User->Category->Depending on category, show the subcategories. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a single page application? If yes, then `$location.path()` would cause your page to reload. Also, I can't understand what is the issue? Is your code not working, if yes, then are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is end url you want? Eg. cat = fruits,vegetables, fruit_subcats = banana, apple, vegetables_subcats = tomato,potato... 1. end subcat url /fruits/banana, /vegetables/tomato. 1. option /banana,/tomato... Namely you want to start subcat from root of url or as second parameter?

Comment: I want to start subcat from root of url, not as a second parameter.
@AyushBahuguna What can i do to not make it reload every time?

Comment: @BleachedAxe look up `$routeParams` if you are using the native angular1.x route module, or `$stateParams` if you are using angular-ui-router. That's what you need to change, the params, and not the pathname.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

Route

```
.when("/category/:category_name", {
    ....
    ....
  })
```

Service

```
.factory('subCategoryService', ['$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', '$cookies','$rootScope', function ($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike, $cookies,$rootScope,category){
          var url2 = 'localhost:5000/api/subcategories/'+httpParamSerializerJQLike.category_name;
        return {getsubCategories: function () {
                return $http.get(url2);

            }}}])
```